# Почему дублируются ответы на запрос?

Tags: mysql

делаю такой запрос

```
SELECT `fl_serial`.`id`,
       `fl_serial`.`name_serial`,
       `fl_serial`.`slug_serial`,
       `fl_serial`.`description_serial`,
       `fl_serial`.`nesting`,
       `fl_serial`.`year`,
       `fl_serial`.`country_title`,
       `fl_film`.`id`,
       `fl_film`.`name_film`,
       `fl_film`.`slug_film`,
       `fl_film`.`description_film`,
       `fl_film`.`nesting`,
       `fl_film`.`year`,
       `fl_film`.`country_title`,
       `fl_mfilm`.`id`,
       `fl_mfilm`.`name_mfilm`,
       `fl_mfilm`.`slug_mfilm`,
       `fl_mfilm`.`description_mfilm`,
       `fl_mfilm`.`nesting`,
       `fl_mfilm`.`year`,
       `fl_mfilm`.`country_title`,
       `fl_cat_serial`.`id`,
       COALESCE(`fl_serial`.`id`, `fl_film`.`id`, `fl_mfilm`.`id`) AS `ids`,
       COALESCE(`fl_serial`.`name_serial`, `fl_film`.`name_film`, `fl_mfilm`.`name_mfilm`) AS `name`,
       COALESCE(`fl_serial`.`slug_serial`, `fl_film`.`slug_film`, `fl_mfilm`.`slug_mfilm`) AS `slug`,
       COALESCE(`fl_serial`.`description_serial`, `fl_film`.`description_film`, `fl_mfilm`.`description_mfilm`) AS `description`,
       COALESCE(`fl_serial`.`nesting`, `fl_film`.`nesting`, `fl_mfilm`.`nesting`) AS `nesting`,
       COALESCE(`fl_serial`.`year`, `fl_film`.`year`, `fl_mfilm`.`year`) AS `years`,
       COALESCE(`fl_serial`.`country_title`, `fl_film`.`country_title`, `fl_mfilm`.`country_title`) AS `country_title`
FROM `fl_cat_serial`
LEFT JOIN `fl_serial` ON fl_cat_serial.id_serial = fl_serial.id
LEFT JOIN `fl_film` ON fl_cat_serial.id_film = fl_film.id
LEFT JOIN `fl_mfilm` ON fl_cat_serial.id_mfilm = fl_mfilm.id
WHERE `fl_cat_serial`.`id_cat`=12
ORDER BY `ids` DESC LIMIT 60
```

получаю такой ответ

```
1617    Тренировочный день (сериал)     serial-Trenirovocnyj-den--      serial  2016    США     NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    8189    1617    Тренировочный день (сериал)     serial-Trenirovocnyj-den--      serial  2016    США
1617    Тренировочный день (сериал)     serial-Trenirovocnyj-den--      serial  2016    США     NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    8196    1617    Тренировочный день (сериал)     serial-Trenirovocnyj-den--      serial  2016    США
1598    Улицы разбитых фонарей (сериал)     serial-Ulicy-razbityh-fonarej-      serial  1997    Россия  NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    7870    1598    Улицы разбитых фонарей (сериал)     serial-Ulicy-razbityh-fonarej-      serial  1997    Россия
1588    19-2 (сериал)   serial-19-2         serial  2014    Канада  NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    7787    1588    19-2 (сериал)   serial-19-2         serial  2014    Канада
1588    19-2 (сериал)   serial-19-2         serial  2014    Канада  NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    7790    1588    19-2 (сериал)   serial-19-2         serial  2014    Канада
```

ну и дальше типа такого почему не подскажите ?

Comment: Вы не могли бы сделать запрос построчно, а то пытаться угадать, где ошибка в строке в 1000+ символов не очень интересно.

Comment: Не вижу дублей, восьмое с конца поле у записей разное. значит у вас участвуют в запросе две записи из той таблицы из которой это поле.

Comment: @Smithson изменили уже

Comment: @Mike да а почему оно возникает ?

Comment: ну если вы переклеиваете таблицы в одной из которых одна запись, а во второй две записи - то на выходе будет разумеется две, запрос же должен показать все возможные результаты. если вам нужна только одна из записей в таблице, то надо определится какая и исходя из этого строить запрос

Comment: @Mike НУ смотрите первых шесть полей абсолютно идентичны почему же возникает возимое с конца поле  имеющее индекс id которое я не вызываю

Comment: Что значит не вызываете. оно из какой вообще таблицы ?

Comment: Мне кажется это id из `fl_cat_serial` вот и сделайте запрос `select * from fl_cat_serial where id_cat=12 and id_serial=1617` мне кажется вы увидите там 2 записи. А почему у вас там две записи и какая из них вам нужна в итогах - это решать вам